# Cmd + D and cmd + control + z don't bring up the In-App Developer Menu react-native iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

I am facing a problem where I can't bring up the In-App Developer Menu on the simulator for react-native iOS. These are the few things I've tried so far:

1. I tried shaking the device manually by going to Hardware -> Shake Gesture
2. I checked that my keyboard is connected by going to hardware -> keyboard -> connect hardware keyboard
3. Made sure that I am running the project on DEBUG mode from xcode-->product-->Scheme-->Edit Scheme -->Run -->Build Configuration -->Debug

This is what I have on my Podfile:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'GebniReact' do

  use_frameworks!


  pod 'Intercom'
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
  pod 'Braintree'
  pod 'BraintreeDropIn', :git => 'https://github.com/braintree/braintree-ios-drop-in.git'
  pod 'Braintree/Venmo'
  pod 'Braintree/Apple-Pay'
  pod 'Fabric'
  pod 'Crashlytics'
  pod 'react-native-branch', path: '../node_modules/react-native-branch'
  pod 'Branch-SDK', path: '../node_modules/react-native-branch/ios'
  pod 'yoga', path: './../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/yoga/yoga.podspec'
  pod 'React', :path => '../node_modules/react-native', :subspecs => [
  'Core',
  'RCTText',
  'RCTNetwork',
  'RCTWebSocket',
  'BatchedBridge',
  'RCTPushNotification',
  'DevSupport'
  ]
  post_install do |installer|

      installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
          if target.name == 'React'
              target.build_configurations.each do |config|
                  if config.name == 'Debug'
                      config.build_settings['GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS'] ||= ['RCT_DEBUG=1','RCT_DEV=1','RCT_NSASSERT=1']
                  end
              end
          end
      end
  end

 end
```

Any ideas?